# Catch Unit Test Ordering

Tags: c++, unit-testing, catch-unit-test

I would like to use [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) to do unit testing on a C++ lib. However I need the most of the test cases to be run in an order. ie the library needs to be init in a certain way and then users logged in etc. Is there any design pattern for achieving this.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a unit test framework? Most of them have fixtures for this sort of thing.

Comment: If you need them run in a specific order, place function pointers into a vector or array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catch test case order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19694391/catch-test-case-order)

Answer (score 5):

Tests are run sequentially, just as you describe. So the simple answer is you do not have to do anything to get this functionality.

However super-long test functions, with a mix of fixture creation and asserts are considered bad form when unit testing: they become harder to maintain, and it takes longer to isolate the problem. The Catch way of tackling this issue is rather interesting, see [the tutorial on Sections](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md#test-cases-and-sections); I also found this [presentation (video, 67 mins) by Phil Nash](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2LcIp56i-8), where (from about 20:00 to 28:00) he explains quite clearly how sections and nested sections work.